# Invertible function - have one big question

Tags: inverse-function

If I want to state if a function is invertible I have couple of tools.

I can check if the function is odd or even.

If it is even, it is certainly not invertible, since $f(x)=f(-x)$, it is strictly agains definition of invertible function. If it is odd, it does not mean it is invertible, because $sin(x)$ is not invertible(periodic) and odd compound function $\frac{x^3}{x^2-1}$ is also not invertible on all real numbers(without restriction), because there are $x_1 \neq x_2$, but $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ in some cases.

So if I do not want to calculate invertibility of a function with definition, I should go for derivation. If derivation exists on some inside interval of function, I can check stationary points and if they do not represent extreme(for example $x^3$) and is all plus or minus, I can state that this function is on that interval invertible, am I right?

Comment: Since "differentiable" implies "continous" , this is correct and actually the standard way to find monotony-intervals. We can even have derivate $\ 0\ $ at isolated points

Comment: Have another question then :).

So if domain of a function is created only by points, it mean that there cannot be any extreme, because they are only isolated points and thus if it meets x1=/=x2 => f(x1)=/=f(x2), this function is invertible?

Comment: Or it can actually have an extreme, but if it suit the definiton of invertible, it is invertible, right? :D

Comment: If the function is continous, it cannot have a neighborhood around an extreme point , in which the function is invertible. Your condition is the definition of injective, with the proper range , we can invert a function satisfying this condition.